# Nginx: remove port from URL

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu

I got a service running via npm on port 3000.

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/public/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    return 301 http://fake.url:3000$request_uri;
}
```

Its working, i can open the site with browser. But in the URL the :3000 appears. How can i remove it from the URL?

Comment: Use `proxy_pass` please, https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location {
        proxy_pass http://fake.url:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this one before. But now i found my mistake.
I had this line " try_files $uri $uri/ =404; "
After i removed it, proxy_pass http://fake.url:3000; worked just fine

Comment: `try_files` in one location with `proxy_pass` drastically changes the behavior indeed.